# What's the best way to earn REQ points?

Tags: halo-5-guardians

REQ points are needed to buy the packs which contain permanent unlocks and other goodies, but what gamemode/playstyle earns the *most* REQ points?

Comment: This link may help for now, until someone figures out the best answer... https://www.halowaypoint.com/en-us/forums/6e35355aecdf4fd0acdaee3cc4156fd4/topics/quick-req-points/9fffb330-718a-4b11-8732-cd7d664465c8/posts

Answer (score 3):

Ive found that playing warzone earns me the most points, even if my team doesn't win the game I always end up earning somewhere around 1,000-1,700 REQ points

Comment: Agreed, Warzone seems to give roughly triple the payout of traditional Arena matches. The question is whether any of the Arena modes have short enough games to make it worth it when compared to longer Warzones. I don't think that's the case but I would like for someone else to weigh in.

Comment: so yeah, it definitely seems like Warzone is the way to go, but what *in* warzone? Should I focus on base capturing, AI hunting, or Spartan hunting to maximize my REQ gains?

Answer (score 3):

Warzone assault takes about ten mins and gets you about 1.5K requisition points per game. It is clearly the best way to get to get reappoints.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting 10k an hour playing Swat and selling everything back. I don't play warzone and I just want to unlock armor/weapon skins. I also only buy bronze, this gives me at least 4 and usually 6 permanent unlocks an hour.

Answer (score 0):

Warzone assault is probably the fastest because you can complete a match in 6 minutes and you get around 1,600 points.

Comment: This doesn't add anything that any of the other answers don't already state. Please keep in mind that duplicate answers are frowned upon here and may be subject to deletion.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, It is better to do anything in Warzone. But the Assault game mode pays out about half the REQ points for about one-third of the time of a full Warzone match. I usually net a silver pack every 3 to 4 games.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so, from what I see is that people are debating whether WZ Assault or a full WZ game is the best, but there's also the factor of the new mode, WZ Firefight. Firefight I've found actually gives out the most Req Points, XP, and the occasional free Gold Pack. I'd go with WZ Firefight if you need Req Points.